# Imagemagick crop not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, height, width, crop

I was trying to perform a crop on a image using imagemagick. It did not give the results I expected.
I decided to set the crop value to 0 to try and find the error.
With a crop value of 0 the image was still being cropped.

Here is the code:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage("{german-grammar.pdf}[17]");
$img->trimImage(10);
$width = $img->getImageWidth();
$height= $img->getImageHeight();
$img->setImagePage($width,$height, 0, 0); //Solution
$img->cropImage($width, $height,0,0); //Original Problem lime
$img->setImagePage(0,0,0,0);
$img->writeImage($ImagesPath.$ImageName);
```

The input is a PDF file.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong.
Surely a crop value of 0 should not crop at all.

Thanks!

Cymro

Comment: Any reason for not using `writeImage()` at the end? Can you simplify your code down to the minimum that doesn't work and give the dimensions of the input image and the resulting output image?

Comment: Mark, have included 2 images and indicated the line which is causing the odd behaviour.  writeImage() did not work for me.  After googling, I read a post about using file_put_contents with Imagemagick and it worked fine.

Comment: Mark, tried out writeImage() again, this time it worked. Have updated the code above to show writeImage().

Comment: Try repaging the image after the `trim` but before the `crop`

Comment: Mark, it worked. Thanks. Why not provide any answer and then I can accept it. Gives you points I think and you've earned them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to repage your image immediately after the `trimImage()` and before the `cropImage()`. It is generally a good idea to repage an image after any changes to its geometry (such as trimming and resizing) if you want the image to *forget* that it was once part of a larger image and go forth in the world happy and content with its own new shape and size.

Comment: The code in my question has been updated to show the suggested solution.

Comment: Well done for being community-minded and showing everyone how it was solved!